I am getting com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4:
I am using Firebase auth to signin user with Google, and I have setup the Firebase project with proper configuration and google-services.json and add that to my android project.
I have added below dependencies in my
build-gradle.kts(project) id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.1" apply false
build.gradle.kts(app)  implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1") implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0")) implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.0.0")
This is my mainactivity.ky
```private fun signIn(){
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, SIGNIN_CODE)
    }
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == SIGNIN_CODE) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.id)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
    }```

This is giving me random results, I am able to log in successfully sometimes, and sometimes I am getting com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4:  exception, I am not sure what is wrong, I tried everything, to add value ofdefault_web_client_id to string.xml to remove that, and invalidate and restart my projects too.
does anyone faces this issue, then how can you resolve it, can you help me with that?

Sorry, I found a minor bug in the code, I have to sign out from the googleSignInClient too, so if any of you face this issue, make sure to signout from firebase and googleSignInClient too.
Thank you.
